# discord.py bot not creating channels

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm writing my code for a command that will make my bot save a certain category's name (specified by the user)  to a .YAML file, and then add a voice channel to it and, if one isn't present already, also add a text channel.

```py
@bot.command()
@has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def hub_create(ctx, *category):
    if discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.categories, name=' '.join(category[:])) != None:
        catname = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.categories, name=' '.join(category[:]))
        with open (r'C:\Users\Cindyarta\PycharmProjects\voicerooms\%s.yaml' % ' '.join(category[:]), 'a+') as file:
            yaml.dump([' '.join(category[:])], file)
            yaml.dump(['0'], file)
            CategoryChannel = catname
            await ctx.guild.create_voice_channel('AFK Room', category=catname)
            if len(CategoryChannel.text_channels) == 0:
                await ctx.guild.create_text_channel('voice-rooms', category=catname)
            await ctx.send("Hub created.")
    else:
        await ctx.send("Not a valid category. Please check if it exists or if I can see it.")
@hub_create.error
async def hub_create_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, CheckFailure):
        await ctx.send("Not a valid category. Please check if it exists or if I can see it.")
```

Problem is that while the code will create and write to the .YAML file, the code does nothing else. The IDE doesn't even show an error.

Can anyone help me find the problem?

Comment: first use `print()` to see values in variables and which part of code is executed - it is called "print debuging".

Comment: Placing a print statement after "ctx.guild.create_voice_channel" will not return anything, but placing it before that will.

Comment: So I've replaced the variable in the category argument with the category ID and the category name. Both of them wield the same result, which means it's something with the function itself.

Comment: at least you know where is problem. Now you can try to find documentation, isuess or tutorials which use this command. Maybe there will be some information. Maybe it need some special values or privileges.

Answer (score 0):

Your error handler is suppressing the exception.  You need to add

```
else:
    raise error
```

so it will propagate the error back up if it can't handle it.  The below works for me, but my bot might have different permissions than yours.

```
@bot.command()
@has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def hub_create(ctx, *, category: discord.CategoryChannel):
    with open (r'C:\Users\Cindyarta\PycharmProjects\voicerooms\%s.yaml' % category.name, 'a+') as file:
        yaml.dump([category.name], file)
        yaml.dump(['0'], file)
    await category.create_voice_channel('AFK Room')
    if len(category.text_channels) == 0:
        await category.create_text_channel('voice-rooms')
    await ctx.send("Hub created.")

@hub_create.error
async def hub_create_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, BadArgument):
        await ctx.send("Not a valid category. Please check if it exists or if I can see it.")
    elif isinstance(error, CheckFailure):
        await ctx.send("Admins only.")
    else:
        raise error
```